# Deleting entities in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure

I have to achieve the deletion of entities in a Azure Table without specifying partition key and row key using C#.

My partition key would be a new GUID and row key is incremental value for a batch.

Comment: Please tell us what you have done so far and what's the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete entries without specifying PK/RK in C# from Azure table storage - unless you delete the whole table

You can do one of the following to delete entries from a storage table:

- Retrieve the entries from the storage to find out their PK/RK and then delete them
- Store their PK/RK's in some other store and issue delete commands using that other source for PK/RK knowledge
- know a pattern to calculate PK/RKs and use that to delete by them
- delete the whole table.  you can partition tables by month or week to help with this strategy